# Linq / Remove whitespace returns actual value 'system.char'

Tags: c#, linq

I do not understand the output that I am getting.

**I have the following code:**

```
    string s = "hello hello";
    s = s.ToCharArray().Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray().ToString();
```

For some reason s returns 'System.Char[]' instead of 'hellohello"

What am I missing?

I understand that this can be done with `REGEX` or other ways. I am just curious about any error I made.

Comment: you can also use this to remove white spaces: s.Replace("  ", string.empty);

Comment: You are fine up to the point where you use `.ToString()`.  At that point, you have a array of 10 chars.  Using `ToString()` on a char array gives you the name of the object (`System.Char[]`), not the result of concatenating the elements in the array into a string.

Comment: why did you remove the answer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `ToString()` on an array of characters, hence the value 'System.Char[]'

Try using

```
new string(s.ToCharArray().Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray())
```

instead (note that this removes the call to `ToString()` on the array produced by `ToArray()`)

Answer (score 3):

Remove  **`ToString()`** from the query which will return **`'System.Char[]'`** . You can remove all white space characters using

```
s = new string(s.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
```